# DES CBC mode not outputting correctly

Tags: c, encryption, cryptography, des, cbc-mode

I am working on a project in C to implement CBC mode on top of a skeleton code for DES with OpenSSL. We are not allowed to use a function that does the CBC mode automatically, in the sense that we must implement it ourselves. I am getting output but I have result files and my output is not matching up completely with the intended results. I also am stuck on figuring out how to pad the file to ensure all the blocks are of equal size, which is probably one of the reasons why I'm not receiving the correct output. Any help would be appreciated. Here's my modification of the skeleton code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/des.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define ENC 1
#define DEC 0

DES_key_schedule key;

int  append(char*s, size_t size, char c) {
    if(strlen(s) + 1 >= size) {
        return 1;
    }
    int len = strlen(s);
    s[len] = c;
    s[len+1] = '\0';
    return 0;
}

int getSize (char * s) {
    char * t;
    for (t = s; *t != '\0'; t++)
        ;
    return t - s;
}

void strToHex(const_DES_cblock input, unsigned char *output) {
    int arSize = 8;
    unsigned int byte;
    for(int i=0; i<arSize; i++) {
        if(sscanf(input, "%2x", &byte) != 1) {
            break;
        }
        output[i] = byte;
        input += 2;
    }

}

void doBitwiseXor(DES_LONG *xorValue, DES_LONG* data, const_DES_cblock roundOutput) {
    DES_LONG temp[2];
    memcpy(temp, roundOutput, 8*sizeof(unsigned char));
    for(int i=0; i<2; i++) {
        xorValue[i] = temp[i] ^ data[i];
    }
}

void doCBCenc(DES_LONG *data, const_DES_cblock roundOutput, FILE *outFile) {

    DES_LONG in[2];
    doBitwiseXor(in, data, roundOutput);

    DES_encrypt1(in,&key,ENC);

    printf("ENCRYPTED\n");
    printvalueOfDES_LONG(in);

    printf("%s","\n");
    fwrite(in, 8, 1, outFile);

    memcpy(roundOutput, in, 2*sizeof(DES_LONG));
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
        const_DES_cblock cbc_key = {0x01,0x23,0x45,0x67,0x89,0xab,0xcd,0xef};
        const_DES_cblock IV = {0x01,0x23,0x45,0x67,0x89,0xab,0xcd,0xef};

        // Initialize the timing function
        struct timeval start, end;
        gettimeofday(&start, NULL);

        int l;
        if ((l = DES_set_key_checked(&cbc_key,&key)) != 0)
            printf("\nkey error\n");

        FILE *inpFile;
        FILE *outFile;
        inpFile = fopen("test.txt", "r");
        outFile = fopen("test_results.txt", "wb");

        if(inpFile && outFile) {
        unsigned char ch;

        // A char array that will hold all 8 ch values.
        // each ch value is appended to this.
        unsigned char eight_bits[8];

        // counter for the loop that ensures that only 8 chars are done at a time.
        int count = 0;

        while(!feof(inpFile)) {
                // read in a character
                ch = fgetc(inpFile);

                // print the character
                printf("%c",ch);

                // append the character to eight_bits
                append(eight_bits,1,ch);

                // increment the count so that we only go to 8.
                count++;
                
                const_DES_cblock roundOutput;
                // When count gets to 8
                if(count == 8) {
                    // for formatting
                    printf("%s","\n");

                    // Encrypt the eight characters and store them back in the char array.
                    //DES_encrypt1(eight_bits,&key,ENC);
                    doCBCenc(eight_bits, roundOutput, outFile);

                    // prints out the encrypted string
                    int k;
                    for(k = 0; k < getSize(eight_bits); k++){
                        printf("%c", eight_bits[k]);

                    }

                    // Sets count back to 0 so that we can do another 8 characters.
                    count = 0;

                    // so we just do the first 8. When everything works REMOVE THE BREAK.
                    //break;
                }
            }

        } else {
            printf("Error in opening file\n");
        }

        fclose(inpFile);
        fclose(outFile);

         // End the timing
        gettimeofday(&end, NULL);
 
        // Initialize seconds and micros to hold values for the time output
        long seconds = (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec);
        long micros = ((seconds * 1000000) + end.tv_usec) - (start.tv_usec);
 
        // Output the time
        printf("The elapsed time is %d seconds and %d microseconds\n", seconds, micros);

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your crypto is at least half correct, but you have a lot of actual or potential other errors.

As you identified, raw CBC mode can only encrypt data which is a multiple of the block size, for DES 64 bits or 8 bytes (on most modern computers and all where you could use OpenSSL). In some applications this is okay; for example if the data is (always) an MD5 or SHA-256 or SHA-512 hash, or a GUID, or an IPv6 (binary) address, then it is a block multiple. But most applications want to handle at least any length in bytes, so they need to use some scheme to pad on encrypt and unpad on decrypt the last block (all blocks before the last already have the correct size). Many different schemes have been developed for this, so you need to know which to use. I assume this is a school assignment (since no real customer would set such a stupid and wasteful combination of requirements) and this should either have been specified or clearly left as a choice. One padding scheme very common today (although not for single-DES, because that is broken, unsafe, obsolete, and *not* common) is the one defined by PKCS5 and generalized by PKCS7 and variously called [PKCS5, PKCS7, or PKCS5/7 padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS#5_and_PKCS#7), so I used that as an example.

Other than that:

- you try to test `feof(inpFile)` before doing `fgetc(inpFile)`. This doesn't work in C. It results in your code treating the low 8 bits of EOF (255 aka 0xFF on practically all implementations) as a valid data character added to the characters that were actually in the file. The common idiom is to store the return of `getchar/getc/fgetc` in a *signed* `int` and compare to `EOF`, but that would have required more changes so I used an alternate.
- you don't initialize `eight_bits` which is a local-scope automatic duration variable, so its contents are undefined and depending on the implementation are often garbage, which means trying to 'append' to it by using `strlen()` to look for the end won't work right and might even crash. Although on some implementations at least some times it might happen to contain zero bytes, and 'work'. In addition it is possible in C for a byte read from a file (and stored here) to be `\0` which will also make this work wrong, although *if* this file contains text, as its name suggests, it *probably* doesn't contain any `\0` bytes.
- once you fill `eight_bits` you write 'off-the-end' into element `[8]` which doesn't exist. Technically this is Undefined Behavior and anything at all can happen, traditionally expressed on Usenet as [nasal demons](http://www.catb.org/%7Eesr/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html). Plus after `main` finishes the first block it doesn't change anything in `eight_bits` so all further calls to `append` find it full and discard the new character.
- while you could fix the above points separately, a much simple solution is available: you are already using `count` to count the number of bytes in the current block, so just use it as the subscript.
- `roundOutput` is also an uninitialized local/auto variable within the loop, which is then used as the previous block for the CBC step, possibly with garbage or wrong value(s). And you don't use the IV at all, as is needed. You should allocate this before the loop (so it retains its value through all iterations) and initialize it to the IV, and then for each block in the loop your `doCBCenc` can properly XOR it to the new block and then leave the encrypted new block to be used next time.
- your code labelled 'prints out the encrypted string' prints *plaintext* not *ciphertext* -- which is binary and shouldn't be printed directly anyway -- and is not needed because your file-read loop already echoes each character read. But if you do want to print a (validly null-terminated) string it's easier to just use `fputs(s)` or `[f]printf([f,]"%s",s)` or even `fwrite(s,1,strlen(s),f)`.
- your `doCBCenc` has a reference to `printvalueofDES_LONG` which isn't defined anywhere, and which along with two surrounding `printf` is clearly not needed.
- you should use a cast to convert the first argument to `doCBCenc` -- this isn't strictly required but is good style and a good compiler (like mine) complains if you don't
- finally, when an error occurs you usually print a message but then continue running, which will never work right and may produce symptoms that disguise the problem and make it hard to fix.

The below code fixes the above except that last (which would have been more work for less benefit) plus I removed routines that are now superfluous, and the timing code which is just silly: Unix already has builtin tools to measure and display process time more easily *and* reliably than writing code. Code I 'removed' is under `#if 0` for reference, and code I added under `#else` or `#if 1` except for the cast. The logic for PKCS5/7 padding is under `#if MAYBE` so it can be either selected or not. Some consider it better style to use `sizeof(DES_block)` or define a macro instead of the magic 8's, but I didn't bother -- especially since it would have required changes that aren't really necessary.

```
// SO70209636
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/des.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define ENC 1
#define DEC 0

DES_key_schedule key;

#if 0
int  append(char*s, size_t size, char c) {
    if(strlen(s) + 1 >= size) {
        return 1;
    }
    int len = strlen(s);
    s[len] = c;
    s[len+1] = '\0';
    return 0;
}

int getSize (char * s) {
    char * t;
    for (t = s; *t != '\0'; t++)
        ;
    return t - s;
}

void strToHex(const_DES_cblock input, unsigned char *output) {
    int arSize = 8;
    unsigned int byte;
    for(int i=0; i<arSize; i++) {
        if(sscanf(input, "%2x", &byte) != 1) {
            break;
        }
        output[i] = byte;
        input += 2;
    }

}
#endif

void doBitwiseXor(DES_LONG *xorValue, DES_LONG* data, const_DES_cblock roundOutput) {
    DES_LONG temp[2];
    memcpy(temp, roundOutput, 8*sizeof(unsigned char));
    for(int i=0; i<2; i++) {
        xorValue[i] = temp[i] ^ data[i];
    }
}

void doCBCenc(DES_LONG *data, const_DES_cblock roundOutput, FILE *outFile) {

    DES_LONG in[2];
    doBitwiseXor(in, data, roundOutput);

    DES_encrypt1(in,&key,ENC);
#if 0
    printf("ENCRYPTED\n");
    printvalueOfDES_LONG(in);
    printf("%s","\n");
#endif
    fwrite(in, 8, 1, outFile);

    memcpy(roundOutput, in, 2*sizeof(DES_LONG));
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
        const_DES_cblock cbc_key = {0x01,0x23,0x45,0x67,0x89,0xab,0xcd,0xef};
        const_DES_cblock IV = {0x01,0x23,0x45,0x67,0x89,0xab,0xcd,0xef};
#if 0
        // Initialize the timing function
        struct timeval start, end;
        gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
#endif
        int l;
        if ((l = DES_set_key_checked(&cbc_key,&key)) != 0)
            printf("\nkey error\n");
#if 1
        DES_cblock roundOutput; // must be outside the loop
        memcpy (roundOutput, IV, 8); // and initialized
#endif

        FILE *inpFile;
        FILE *outFile;
        inpFile = fopen("test.txt", "r");
        outFile = fopen("test.encrypt", "wb");

        if(inpFile && outFile) {
        unsigned char ch;

        // A char array that will hold all 8 ch values.
        // each ch value is appended to this.
        unsigned char eight_bits[8];

        // counter for the loop that ensures that only 8 chars are done at a time.
        int count = 0;

#if 0
        while(!feof(inpFile)) {
                // read in a character
                ch = fgetc(inpFile);
#else
        while( ch = fgetc(inpFile), !feof(inpFile) ){
#endif
                // print the character
                printf("%c",ch);
#if 0
                // append the character to eight_bits
                append(eight_bits,1,ch);
                // increment the count so that we only go to 8.
                count++;
#else
                eight_bits[count++] = ch;
#endif
                
#if 0
                const_DES_cblock roundOutput;
#endif
                // When count gets to 8
                if(count == 8) {
                    // for formatting
                    printf("%s","\n");

                    // Encrypt the eight characters and store them back in the char array.
                    //DES_encrypt1(eight_bits,&key,ENC);
                    doCBCenc((DES_LONG*)eight_bits, roundOutput, outFile);
#if 0
                    // prints out the encrypted string
                    int k;
                    for(k = 0; k < getSize(eight_bits); k++){
                        printf("%c", eight_bits[k]);

                    }
#endif
                    // Sets count back to 0 so that we can do another 8 characters.
                    count = 0;

                    // so we just do the first 8. When everything works REMOVE THE BREAK.
                    //break;
                }
            }
#if MAYBE
            memset (eight_bits+count, 8-count, 8-count); // PKCS5/7 padding
            doCBCenc((DES_LONG*)eight_bits, roundOutput, outFile);
#endif
        } else {
            printf("Error in opening file\n");
        }

        fclose(inpFile);
        fclose(outFile);
#if 0
         // End the timing
        gettimeofday(&end, NULL);
        // Initialize seconds and micros to hold values for the time output
        long seconds = (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec);
        long micros = ((seconds * 1000000) + end.tv_usec) - (start.tv_usec);
        // Output the time
        printf("The elapsed time is %d seconds and %d microseconds\n", seconds, micros);
#endif
}
```

PS: personally I wouldn't put the `fwrite` in `doCBCenc`; I would only do the encryption and let the caller do whatever I/O is appropriate which might in some cases *not* be `fwrite`. But what you have is not wrong for the requirements you apparently have.

Comment: This is such a great comprehensive answer, thanks so much.